# Add a preview to a Wordpress Control Panel

Tags: theme-development, css, templates, ajax, theme-options

I'm trying to create a new wordpress template and inside it I added a Control Panel, inside this control panel there is an option that allows user to choose where he want's to place a  on a map, I try to explain: user can set div's left and top attributes via control panel.
Now I know how to add an iframe that can show a preview of the changes but it doesn't work as I would like (how to add the preview? read here: [Modify CSS via Theme Control Panel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12627/modify-css-via-theme-control-panel)) What I would like to add is a **real time** preview. As soon as the user modify TOP or LEFT attribute preview has to show what it is happening without showing it to "live" blog.

Here is my function.php:

```
array( "name" => "Before we start",
    "type" => "section"),
array( "type" => "open"),
array( "name" => "Where is the map?",
    "desc" => "Insert map page url",
    "id" => $shortname."_pama",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => "http://examplepage.com"),
array( "type" => "close"),
array( "name" => "Zona 1",
    "type" => "section"),
array( "type" => "open"),
array(  "name" => "Activate zona 1?",
    "desc" => "Choose yes or no",
    "id" => $shortname."_zona1c",
    "type" => "checkbox",
    "std" => "false"),
array( "name" => "Zona 1 X-Axis",
    "desc" => "Where do you want it on x-axis?",
    "id" => $shortname."_zona1x",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => "Left:???"),
array( "name" => "Zona 1 Y-Axis",
    "desc" => "Where do you want it on y-axis?",
    "id" => $shortname."_zona1y",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => "Top:???"),
array( "type" => "close"),
array( "name" => "Zona 1",
    "type" => "section"),
array( "type" => "open"),
array(  "name" => "Activate zona 2?",
    "desc" => "Choose yes or no",
    "id" => $shortname."_zona1c",
    "type" => "checkbox",
    "std" => "false"),
array( "name" => "Zona 2 X-Axis",
    "desc" => "Choose where you want it on X-Axis",
    "id" => $shortname."_zona2x",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => "Left:???"),
array( "name" => "Zona 2 Y-Axis",
    "desc" => "Choose where you want it on Y-Axis",
    "id" => $shortname."_zona2y",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => "Top:???"),
array( "type" => "close"),
array( "type" => "close"),
);
```

This is the iframe that I use to show the preview inside Control Panel:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo clean_url(apply_filters('preview_post_link', add_query_arg('preview', 'true', get_option('appacqua_pama')))); ?>" width="100%" height="600" ></iframe>
```

Ok, now the big question is there a STEP TO STEP way to add a preview on real time (I don't know how to explain it better, I'm really sorry...), what do you think will it be possible to use ajax? (I heard about it but I'm not a programmer so please write in a Dummy Proof way!!!) Will I need to add also a PREVIEW button instead of only SAVE button? How to add it? Do you know Mystique theme by digitalnature? something like this will be GREAT! If you can't write it here why don't you write a very good, and step to step, tutorial on your website? There is a lack of good articles about how to create a very good Theme-Option panel with a lot of functionalities for wordpress 3.x maybe you'll be the next and you'll also help us...poor noobs :-)
Thank you very much for your time and patience!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at Mystique theme (a great example of option panel with preview BTW) you can see that the main idea is to lavrage the form fields OnChange or change() events to load the theme's preview with Jquery and a bit of ajax.

So you have one function to load by ajax the preview

```
function mystique_get_site_preview() {
  check_ajax_referer("site_preview"); ?>
  <iframe id="themepreview" name="themepreview" src="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/?preview=1"></iframe>
  <?php die();
}
```

and to create the auto preview effect you use some JQuery with PHP:

```
$nonce = wp_create_nonce('site_preview');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#$zona1y").change(function() {// if a user changed the y-Axis
            check_preview_refresh();
            }
        );
        jQuery("#$zona1x").change(function() {// if a user changed the x-Axis
            check_preview_refresh();
            }
        );
    });

    function check_preview_refresh(){
        if (jQuery("#zona1y").val() != '' && jQuery("#zona1x").val() != '' ){
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "post",url: "admin-ajax.php",data: { action: 'site_preview', _ajax_nonce: '<?php echo $nonce; ?>' },
                success: function(html){
                    jQuery("#themepreview").html(html);
                    jQuery("#themepreview").show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now this code assumes that you have two input fields with the id of "zona1y" and "zona1y"
and a div wrapping your Iframe with the id of "themepreview".

and that should get you started.

### Update:

I forgot you will need to add:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_site_preview', 'mystique_get_site_preview');
```

Now

the first part + the last line of code go in your functions.php

and the second part needs to go on your theme option panel page.

Comment: @Bairnet 
First thing to say...Thank you for your fast reply :-)
Second thing...let's try to understand, what I have to do now is:
1 - Take this: function mystique_get_site_preview() {
  check_ajax_referer("site_preview"); ?>
  <iframe id="themepreview" name="themepreview" src="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/?preview=1"></iframe>
  <?php die();
}
and add my template shortname (appacqua is the shortname) then overwrite my existing iframe preview code.
2 - take the second part of the code that you gave me and add it to my function.php?
Am I right?

Comment: @Bainternet (first time I used a bad @ tag...Sorry!) Will I need to add a preview button? How does it works? Have you seen my function? Will it work with it? Actually the only way to see modifications is to save the new position... so, once again, Will it work?

Comment: @Downloadtaky: i updated my answer.

Comment: @Bainternet I'm doing something wrong for sure!
Each time I try to save the option it gives me: 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/nextube/public_html/wp-content/themes/appartamentiacquario/functions.php:434) in /home/nextube/public_html/wp-content/themes/appartamentiacquario/functions/cpanelfunction.php on line 191
Here you can see my files:

Here is my function.php code:
http://pastebin.com/8cVmne1s
Here is optionpanel.php:
http://pastebin.com/jvTx2MYX
Here is postdropdown.php
http://pastebin.com/qWVrXqV3

Comment: Here is adminfoot.php
http://pastebin.com/NET7TfZr
Here is cpanelfunction.php
http://pastebin.com/xJv7F66w
Here is firstimage.php
http://pastebin.com/0KxeetNx
Here is regsidebar.php
http://pastebin.com/wPcDaAu5

Comment: I don't want to abuse of your or any other patience but... I'm going crazy!
P.S.
The core of my theme is Twenty Ten :-)

Comment: I'll take a look as soon as i'll get home.

Comment: @Bainternet thank you very much, you are the best, anyway I'm still trying to solve it by my self, as I think you understood I'm not a programmer but a "wanna be" and I'm not english mothertongue too :-) Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to the way the option panel saves the changes, any possible different solution? Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe problems started when I splitted my function.php into parts so I tried to change:
'code' header("Location: admin.php?page=/functions.php&saved=true"); 'code'
Into this:
'code' header("Location: admin.php?page=/functions/cpanelfunction.php&saved=true"); 'code'
But...No solution yet :-(

Comment: Edit, I hope you didn't checked my pastebin before because I have just updated them with my new modifactions and I added also 2 new files:
functions/firstimage.php = http://pastebin.com/iWW1Z1KJ
functions/regsidebar.php = http://pastebin.com/vmM7vQQD
Now error is: 
**bold** Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/nextube/public_html/wp-content/themes/appartamentiacquario/functions/cpanelfunction.php:2) in /home/nextube/public_html/wp-content/themes/appartamentiacquario/functions/cpanelfunction.php on line 189 **bold** so something changed...

Comment: Now in Italy is 02:36 AM so I'm going to sleep, I hope you can help me, if you have enough free time, if you can't (i can understand it) I will look for a different solution to save the modification without the need of using `header("Location: admin.php?page=/functions.php&saved=true"); `,
maybe I'll follow this tutorial: http://www.mojo-themes.com/2010/09/create-a-wordpress-option-panel/

Comment: @Downloadtaky: OK found the problem, you are using HTML comments `<!-- blabla -->` in your php files, **DONT DO THAT** because it sets an output and that is why you get "headers  already sent by..."  use php comments instead.

Comment: @Bainternet now I have no errors (I changed a few things because I'm trrying to keep things cleaner and separated) but preview doesn't work...
I can see the iframe but the only way to see changes is to save them...
I'm going crazy!

Comment: This is my new admin-panel.php : http://pastebin.com/iDiHxbHs ;
this is my new functions.php : http://pastebin.com/jmFZ0H31

Comment: @Bainternet
Update: my functions.php: http://pastebin.com/8cVmne1s
My admin-panel.php: http://pastebin.com/xX8G4Zxr
My preview.js (the script you gave me): http://pastebin.com/tb0ueTEi
My stylemappa.php : http://pastebin.com/pih7yaT1

Chrome inspect says that I have an error in load-scripts.php:84

Comment: @Bainternet
'Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #$zona1y
k.errorload-scripts.php:84
k.filterload-scripts.php:84
kload-scripts.php:80
t.querySelectorAll.kload-scripts.php:101
c.fn.extend.findload-scripts.php:104
c.b.fn.b.initload-scripts.php:25
c.bload-scripts.php:22
(anonymous function)preview.js:2
c.b.extend.readyload-scripts.php:29
c.uload-scripts.php:37'

If it can be helpfull I'm using jQuery 1.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Even though it appears the author solved his request, I'll post a better solution on how to achieve this (I'm also the author of Mystique btw). Maybe it will help others.

So, first you need the iframe document - your home page. I'm using ajax to get it just like in the function above, but you don't necessarily need to do this. You can just normally add the iframe above your theme setting fields, just like any HTML.

Remember to append a query argument to the iframe target URL, like `<?php home_url(); ?>/?themepreview` (or user add_query_arg or whatever). This is important, you'll see later.

Next, you need to find a way to communicate with the iframe. Check out the [postMessage](http://postmessage.freebaseapps.com/) and [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) scripts. Enqueue them in your settings page.

Now, simply bind a function on the events you need to the live preview to fire. For example, assuming you have a text input named "page_width":

```
<input name="page_width" />
```

in your jQuery document.ready function you would have something like this:

```
// event can be anything, click/change/input or a custom colorpicker event...
$("input[name='page_width']").change(function(){

  // get the value entered by the user
  var current_page_width = $(this).val();

  // send this value trough postMessage to the iframe document
  pm({
    target: window.frames["themepreview"],  // this needs to be the iframe ID
    type: 'page_width',
    data: current_page_width
  });
});
```

So the `pm` function will send the input value to the iframe.

Now for the iframe to change its contents, you need to include the above scripts on the front-end too. But only do this if the query argument above is present, so you only include them when a theme preview is requested, and not on every page load.

In the front-end's document.ready handle the receiving part, with `pm.bind()`:

```
// first argument should be the "type" from above
pm.bind('page_width', function(data){

  // data that's being received is the 'current_page_width', so just set the new width to the element you need to
  $('#page').css('width', data + 'px');

});
```

And that's it :)

You can also find sample code in version 3 of Mystique...